# Fano's geometry and communication network

Tags: geometry

I saw in the web saying that Fano geometry and communication networks has some similarity.  In switching box a user is identified as a point and a line is identified as a switch. My objection to this idea is that in Fano geometry, there are three points on a line by axiom and it means that in communication network there are three users on a switch(connected). This is a situation to avoid in communication network since it is a mixed line or wire-tapped condition. Am I missing something?

Comment: It would have been useful to know *here* on the web you saw that. As you describe it, it indeed doesn't seem to make soo much sense, but perhaps the context of that webpage either gave some meaning to the third item on the line that you missed, or considered a similarity at some level where that aspect doesn't matter, or concentrated on an affine portion of the Fano plane, or something like that. Hard to tell without reading the page.

Comment: Here is the website.  http://www-math.ucdenver.edu/~wcherowi/courses/m3210/lecture2.pdf       and http://www-math.ucdenver.edu/~wcherowi/courses/m3210/lecture1.pdf